# SQL restore is failing with an error when using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-administration, database-restore, ssms-2017

SQL restore is failing with an error with the below error. The backup is from 2008 and tried on 2017 and 2017 express, it fails. The .bak size is 100 MB.

[image]

Comment: This question really looks like it belongs on [Database Administrators.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: I'm automatically suspicious of a database being called `BCP`. Is this really an SQL Server `.bak` backup file, or is it an export from the [`bcp.exe` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) that someone has renamed to have a `.bak` extension?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the database name itself is bcp and  I tried with more than 5 databases from 2008 and it fails with the same error message. The same .bak file works again if I restore in 2008 . It is back up from ssms in 2008 and no utility etc

Comment: @squillman SSMS 18

Comment: Hard to tell because the screen shot is cropped so much, but that kind of looks like the Database > Tasks > Restore > Files and Filegroups... wizard. You might want to try the Database > Tasks > Restore > Database... wizard instead.

Comment: Also if you continue to have problems... near the top-left corner of the SSMS wizard windows is usually a Script button. Choose Script > New Query Editor Window to show the T-SQL script that the wizard intends to use and then edit your SO question to include that script.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Restore database works but it is strange that it fails using restore >files and filegroups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database > Tasks > Restore > Database... wizard has worked. Thank you @AlwaysLearning